# Rounding in Google Query Language

Tags: gql, scalar

I'd like to implement a series of queries with rounding in Google Query Language, such as:

```
select round(age,-1), count(id) group by round(age,-1)
```

or any combination of int/floor/etc.

```
select int(age/10)*10, count(id) group by int(age/10)*10
```

Is there any way to do that?  I suspect no, as the list of scalar functions in GQL is very limited, but do wonder if there's a workaround.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage.html#scalar_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I dont think we can do rounding in GQL...

The link that you have shown is not for google app engine...

Answer (score 3):

Add a format at the end of the query, for example:

```
"select age format age '0'"
```

See [Google Query Language Reference - Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#format).

Answer (score 2):

Although there are no explicit round or floor functions, one can implement them using the modulus operator `%` and the fact that `value % 1` returns the decimal part of `value`. So `value - value % 1` is equivalent to `floor(value)`, at least for positive values. More generally `value - value % k` should be equivalent to `floor(value / k) * k`.

In your case, your query should look like:

```
select age - age % 10, count(id) group by age - age % 10
```